# how symbolic representation of function description works on php.net

Tags: php

Below is the description of `in_array` function on php.net website.

Can someone explain what the the mean that "The array start symbol `[` followed by comma and it end after `FALSE` at the end."

```
Description ¶
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/about.prototypes.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are optional parameters with the default value. If you don't specify then, it will use false.

Official documentation ~ http://php.net/manual/about.prototypes.php

Comment: I think you should add the link in @Phil comment to the answer